# Sequelize.js foreign key

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

When using Sequelize.js, the following code doesn't add any foreign key on tables.

```
var MainDashboard = sequelize.define('main_dashboard', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
})

MainClient.hasOne(MainDashboard, { foreignKey: 'idClient' })
MainDashboard.hasOne(MainClient, { foreignKey: 'clientId' })

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
```

Is there any way to force Sequelize.js to add these foreign key constraints?

Comment: Isn't there a thing called ForeignKey: true attribute which can be set in the sequelize.define() function for a column?

Answer (score 55):

Before I had the same problem, and solved when I understood the functioning of settings Sequelize.

Straight to the point!

Suppose we have two objects: **Person** and **Father**

```
var Person = sequelize.define('Person', {

        name: Sequelize.STRING
});

var Father = sequelize.define('Father', {

        age: Sequelize.STRING,
        //The magic start here
        personId: {
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
              references: 'persons', // <<< Note, its table's name, not object name
              referencesKey: 'id' // <<< Note, its a column name
        }
});

Person.hasMany(Father); // Set one to many relationship
```

Maybe it helps you

Edit:

You can read this to understand better:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#foreign-keys

Comment: The use of `references` and `referencesKey` is now deprecated => `Utils deprecated Non-object references property found. Support for that will be removed in version 4. Expected { references: { model: "value", key: "key" } } instead of { references: "value", referencesKey: "key" }.`

Comment: this is not a good example, last command says that `one Person has many Fathers` which doesnt sound natural

Answer (score 41):

For Sequelize 4 this has been updated to the following:

```js
const Father = sequelize.define('Father', {
        name: Sequelize.STRING
});

const Child = sequelize.define('Child', {
    age: Sequelize.STRING,
    fatherId: {
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
       references: {
          model: 'fathers', // 'fathers' refers to table name
          key: 'id', // 'id' refers to column name in fathers table
       }
    }
});

Father.hasMany(Child); // Set one to many relationship
```

Edit:
You can read more on associations at https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Answer (score 7):

I just tried to run your code, and the rows seem to be created fine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_dashboard` (`title` VARCHAR(255), `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `idClient` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_client` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment,  `clientId` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`clientId` is added to `main_client`, and `idClient` is added to `main_dashboard`

It seems you have slightly confused what the `hasOne` method does. Each time you call `hasOne` an association is created, so your code effectively associates the two tables twice. The method you are looking for is `belongsTo`

If you want each client to have one dashboard, the code would be the following:

```
MainClient.hasOne(MainDashboard, { foreignKey: 'clientId' })
MainDashboard.belongsTo(MainClient, { foreignKey: 'clientId' })
```

This creates a `clientId` field on the `main_dashboard` table, which relates to the `id` field of the `main_client` table

In short `belongsTo` adds the relation to the table that you are calling the method on, `hasOne` adds it on the table that is given as argument.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `foreignKeyConstraint: true`

Try:

```
MainClient.hasOne(MainDashboard, { foreignKey: 'idClient', foreignKeyConstraint: true })
```

Comment: Is this still an option? I don't see the property `foreignKeyConstraint` in [the API](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-hasOne); only `foreignKey`. Oh! Maybe the property is now called simply: `constraints`?  It is described as : "Should on update and on delete constraints be enabled on the foreign key.

"

Answer (score 2):

It's amazingly simple.

```
const MainDashboard = this.sequelize.define('main_dashboard', {/* attributes */}),
      MainClient    = this.sequelize.define('main_client', {/* attributes */});

MainDashboard.belongsTo(MainClient, { foreignKey: 'clientId' }); // Adds clientId to MainDashboard
```

It will link this as a foreign key and you may use it as an association. Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: I guess, we must also write down foreign key in parent model, that is MainClient, like this: 
    MainClient.hasMany(MainDashboard, { foreignKey: 'clientId' }); 

We must also add column 'clientId' manually to the MainDashboard migration file with an attribute: 'type: DataTypes.INTEGER'.