# Is it possible to force a foreign key to exist using Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

My model is:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return Person = sequelize.define('Person', {
    PersonTime: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    message: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        return Person.hasMany(models.Thought, {
          foreignKey: 'PersonId'
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I want to force every Person to belong to a Thought and therefore in the `Thought` table, I want the `PersonId` field to be required. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you want is probably:

```
Person.hasMany(Thought)
Thought.belongsTo(Person)
```

However I tried that doesn't give you a 'real' foreign key at the database level which is what you want. After some trial and error and searching I came up with this:

```
Thought.belongsTo(Person, { constraints: true, foreignKeyConstraint:true  } );
Person.hasMany(Thought)
```

When you `.sync()` that the SQL created is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persons` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , 
    `PersonTime` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `message` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Thoughts` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    `text` VARCHAR(255), 
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    `PersonId` INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    FOREIGN KEY (`PersonId`) REFERENCES `Persons` (`id`)
);
```

More details in the [documentation](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/associations#foreign-keys), although it was an answer to this question that helped me to make it work: [Sequelize.js foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169655/sequelize-foreign-key)

Comment: This is creating the foreign key so that the `PersonId` needs to match an existing `User`, however it's not requiring the foreign key, so you can end up with `Thoughts` with `PersonId` set to null. I would be interested to know how to require this foreign key value too.

Comment: @maxwell2022 The API docs here (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Associations) say you should be able to force a foreign key to be non-null by passing the details in a foreignKey object to the hasMany()/belongsTo() method. However I can't make that work on my older install, there many be another way but I don't know it -- you may be better to ask a separate question (and link this one) if you want more insight.

Comment: It's what I've done and got the solution if you are interested. Also this is working with the `2.0-rc2`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835688/how-to-force-1n-association-with-sequelizejs/26839975

Comment: @maxwell2022 Ah, thanks. That's what I was trying to do but I was using an older version which is why it didn't work. Good thing to know for the future.