# How to force 1:n association with Sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

I'm implementing some tests to make sure my sequelize objects are saved correctly.
I have a very simple schema: Article <--> Users

> An *Article* is published by **ONE** *User* 
>   A *User* can publish **MANY** *Articles*

Here is my Article model definition:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize){
    "use strict";

    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    ...
    var Article = sequelize.define("Article", {
        slug: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            comment: "Unique URL slug to access the article"
        },
        title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
            }
        },
        summary: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        body: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        published: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: true},
        allowComment: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: true}
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models)
            {
                Article.belongsTo(models.User, {as: "Author", foreignKey: 'author_id'});
                Article.hasMany(models.Comment, {as: "Comments", foreignKey: 'article_id'});
            },
            articlesForIndex: function()
            {
                return this.findAll({
                    where: {published: true},
                    order: 'createdAt DESC',
                    limit: 10
                });
            }
        },
        setterMethods   : {
            title : function(v) {
                this.setDataValue('title', v.toString());
                this.setDataValue('slug', slugify(v));
            }
        }
    });

    return Article;
};
```

What I want to do is forcing the `Article` to have an `Author` (`User`). With the current definition I can create Article without `Author`.

Here is my test that is failing:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, models) {
    'use strict';

    var Q = require('q');
    var should = require('chai').should();

    describe('Article Model', function () {

        describe('Validation', function () {

            ...

            it('should not be valid without an author', function (done) {
                models.Article.create({title: 'title5', summary: 'summary', body: 'body'})
                    .should.be.rejected.notify(done);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On fairly recent (2.0-rc2 i believe) versions of sequelize you can change the foreign key to an object:

```
Article.belongsTo(User, {
    as: "Author", 
    onDelete: 'CASCADE', 
    foreignKey: { name:'author_id', allowNull: false }
});
```

You also need to add `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` because we can no longer set null on delete

Comment: Looks good to me. It's a shame the documentation is not complete :(

Comment: We hope it will be soon, once the final version of 2.0 is out

Comment: I agree that documentation seems like absolutely obsolete! It's a real shame such a great library have that problem. Come on guys - we cannot use all the sugar without knowing it! It just took me half an hour to get to this post (because of not that proper naming)!!!

Comment: I agree with you, but please stop 'come on'-ing us - we are practically 2-4 people working on the project, trying to keep up with bug reports, feature requests, and maintaining the documentation.
You are very welcome to contribute to the documentation - it's hosting in the (GH repo)[github.com/sequelize/sequelize] and PRs are very welcome :)