# Adding associations to sequelizejs models

Tags: node.js, postgresql, associations, sequelize.js

I have defined a model (by using sequelize-cli) as such:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Rating = sequelize.define('Rating', {
  star_count: DataTypes.FLOAT,
  details: DataTypes.TEXT
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Rating.hasOne(models.Product);
  }
 }
});
return Rating;
};
```

However when I query `Rating` in the database after I `db:migrate` I get:

```
SELECT * from "Ratings";
 id | star_count | details | createdAt | updatedAt
----+------------+---------+-----------+-----------
```

The documentation really doesn't say anything different than what I did above. I'd expect to see a `product_id` field in here. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Sequelize-CLI creates a file called `index.js` in models. It looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config.js')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username,     config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) &&     (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
 });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
 });

 db.sequelize = sequelize;
 db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

 module.exports = db;
```

This appears to be calling the `associate` method, which calls the [the appropriate functions](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/) (hasMany, etc) and according to the documentation should set up the right relationships. [This](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/10/22/node-postgres-sequelize/) tutorial seems to corroborate this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequelize migration will create changes according to migration file so you need to specify the foreign key with reference as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23035179/4583460

The Sequelize.sync command will create any aditional keys required for the association. So either use sync or mention change your migration file to include foreign key ref.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  I have updated my explanation with some more clarity. It appears `index.js` in `models` isnt getting called at all so the associations are never created. I'm not sure if this is the same as what you are saying or not. Is this file loaded during migration or only when I `require` a model from `models`?

Comment: No this is not the migration file it there is separate folder. The index.js must be called when require the folder with all your models.

Comment: Also you need to do only one either db migrate or sync,

Comment: oh okay, so if I use `db:migrate` I need to build the associations by hand? Sorry, I'll green check after this question.

Comment: yes if you use migrate you need to specify reference keys and after that mention the foreign key in your associations